No notifications sound & vibration on custom ROM
I'm having a problem with a ported ROM on my device (Redmi Note 7). There are no notifications sounds or vibrations. The ROM came with no ringtones/notifications/alarms or UI.ogg files.
I've tried to add them manually and set the right permissions, but that didn't change anything. Also, I've tried to look for the vibration.ko or kernel modules file but have had no luck.
How to fix this?
